# Microsoft Graph update subscription always results in 403 Forbidden error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using Microsoft Graph I am successfully creating subscriptions, but when calling HTTP Patch to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/ with a correct (works through Graph Explorer) json payload of 
{ "expirationDateTime": "UTCTIME 2 minutes past current expiration"}

I always get 403 Forbidden as a result.

I have the permissions set (I think) correctly to Files.ReadWrite as per https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/subscription_update.  These should be the same permissions as Creating the subscription so can someone help as to why I can create but not update?

Comment: Can you try Files.ReadWrite.All first? based on your current description, we cannot address the cause.

Comment: I've tried Files.ReadWrite.All as well, with the same 403 Forbidden result. I waited a couple hours after making the change in apps.dev.microsoft registration to ensure they were applied as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you reported should be fixed now. Please let me know if you're still seeing 403s on subscription update requests.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the permission on project config but not only the **apps.dev.microsoft** or **azure app portal**.

If you not sure which **config file** to set, just get started from the official [sample code](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start), or just find the keywords "**GraphScope**" in your project and add the **Files.ReadWrite.All**.

You get 403 mainly caused by some wrong config. Still need to check on your side. We can just provide the suggestion to assist you.